# Unity3d and Yii webserivce

Tags: web-services, yii, unity-game-engine

I'm building a server for game code by Unity3d, my server is built with Yii, but when I see guide about webservice of Yii [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice) I saw it use soapClient to call function in server. But in Unity3d i know just WWW and WWWForm to request to server. So, anybody know how to use webservice in Unity3d to communicate with Yii?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You just send data through WWWForm

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

```
var highscore_url = "http://www.my-site.com/?r=MyGame/highscore";
```

And in Yii's Controller: \protected\controller\MyGameController.php

```
class MyGame extends Controller
{
   public function actionHighscore()
   {
      // Here you get data from $_REQUEST ($_POST or $_GET) 
      // and use Yii's power for output some data
      // like perl example in link upthere
   }

}
```